# How to hide or Expose contracts from same WCF service

Tags: wcf

If I have multiple contracts in WCF Service  and All with same binding.Address is also same.then how to expose/hide contract to different application.I mean how to expose End points in this condition.

Answer (score 0):

try to take a look  at the message inspector 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa717047(v=vs.110).aspx 
hope  this help